# SSL handshake exception Wildfly

Tags: java, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, wildfly

I am trying to access the admin ui for **EJBCA 8** deployed on Wildfly 26.0.0.Final, Java 17 via https://10.0.0.16:8443/ejbca/admin...
But I keep on getting this exception:

```
fatal alert: certificate_unknown
```

Full stack trace:

````
2023-09-12 22:14:01,180 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) javax.net.ssl|ALL|CC|default task-1|2023-09-12 22:14:01.179 UTC|X509Authentication.java:304|No X.509 cert selected for EC
2023-09-12 22:14:01,181 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) javax.net.ssl|ALL|CC|default task-1|2023-09-12 22:14:01.180 UTC|X509Authentication.java:304|No X.509 cert selected for EdDSA
2023-09-12 22:14:01,182 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) javax.net.ssl|ALL|CC|default task-1|2023-09-12 22:14:01.182 UTC|X509Authentication.java:304|No X.509 cert selected for EC
2023-09-12 22:14:01,183 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) javax.net.ssl|ALL|CC|default task-1|2023-09-12 22:14:01.183 UTC|X509Authentication.java:304|No X.509 cert selected for EdDSA
2023-09-12 22:14:01,184 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) javax.net.ssl|ALL|CC|default task-1|2023-09-12 22:14:01.183 UTC|X509Authentication.java:304|No X.509 cert selected for EC
2023-09-12 22:14:01,185 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) javax.net.ssl|ALL|CC|default task-1|2023-09-12 22:14:01.184 UTC|X509Authentication.java:304|No X.509 cert selected for EdDSA
2023-09-12 22:14:01,216 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-2) javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|66|default I/O-2|2023-09-12 22:14:01.215 UTC|Alert.java:238|Received alert message (
2023-09-12 22:14:01,216 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-2) "Alert": {
2023-09-12 22:14:01,216 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-2)   "level"      : "fatal",
2023-09-12 22:14:01,216 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-2)   "description": "certificate_unknown"
2023-09-12 22:14:01,217 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-2) }
2023-09-12 22:14:01,217 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-2) )
2023-09-12 22:14:01,219 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-2) javax.net.ssl|ERROR|66|default I/O-2|2023-09-12 22:14:01.218 UTC|TransportContext.java:370|Fatal (CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN): Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown (
2023-09-12 22:14:01,220 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-2) "throwable" : {
2023-09-12 22:14:01,220 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-2)   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
2023-09-12 22:14:01,220 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-2)      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,220 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-2)      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,220 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-2)      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:365)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,220 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-2)      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:293)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,220 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-2)      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:204)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,220 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-2)      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,220 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-2)      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.decode(SSLEngineImpl.java:736)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,221 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-2)      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:691)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,221 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-2)      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:506)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,221 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-2)      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:482)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,221 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-2)      at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:679)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,221 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-2)      at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.server.protocol.http.ALPNLimitingSSLEngine.unwrap(ALPNLimitingSSLEngine.java:75)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,221 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-2)      at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.protocols.ssl.SslConduit.doUnwrap(SslConduit.java:781)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,221 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-2)      at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.protocols.ssl.SslConduit.doHandshake(SslConduit.java:672)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,221 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-2)      at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.protocols.ssl.SslConduit.access$900(SslConduit.java:70)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,221 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-2)      at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.protocols.ssl.SslConduit$SslReadReadyHandler.readReady(SslConduit.java:1215)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,221 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-2)      at org.jboss.xnio.nio@3.8.5.Final//org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.handleReady(NioSocketConduit.java:89)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,221 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-2)      at org.jboss.xnio.nio@3.8.5.Final//org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:591)}
2023-09-12 22:14:01,222 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-2) 
2023-09-12 22:14:01,222 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-2) )
2023-09-12 22:14:01,256 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) javax.net.ssl|ALL|CC|default task-1|2023-09-12 22:14:01.256 UTC|X509Authentication.java:304|No X.509 cert selected for EC
2023-09-12 22:14:01,258 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) javax.net.ssl|ALL|CC|default task-1|2023-09-12 22:14:01.258 UTC|X509Authentication.java:304|No X.509 cert selected for EdDSA
2023-09-12 22:14:01,259 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) javax.net.ssl|ALL|CC|default task-1|2023-09-12 22:14:01.258 UTC|X509Authentication.java:304|No X.509 cert selected for EC
2023-09-12 22:14:01,275 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) javax.net.ssl|ALL|DC|default task-2|2023-09-12 22:14:01.256 UTC|X509Authentication.java:304|No X.509 cert selected for EC
2023-09-12 22:14:01,276 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) javax.net.ssl|ALL|CC|default task-1|2023-09-12 22:14:01.274 UTC|X509Authentication.java:304|No X.509 cert selected for EdDSA
2023-09-12 22:14:01,277 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) javax.net.ssl|ALL|DC|default task-2|2023-09-12 22:14:01.275 UTC|X509Authentication.java:304|No X.509 cert selected for EdDSA
2023-09-12 22:14:01,277 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) javax.net.ssl|ALL|CC|default task-1|2023-09-12 22:14:01.277 UTC|X509Authentication.java:304|No X.509 cert selected for EC
2023-09-12 22:14:01,278 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) javax.net.ssl|ALL|CC|default task-1|2023-09-12 22:14:01.277 UTC|X509Authentication.java:304|No X.509 cert selected for EdDSA
2023-09-12 22:14:01,278 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) javax.net.ssl|ALL|DC|default task-2|2023-09-12 22:14:01.277 UTC|X509Authentication.java:304|No X.509 cert selected for EC
2023-09-12 22:14:01,279 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) javax.net.ssl|ALL|DC|default task-2|2023-09-12 22:14:01.278 UTC|X509Authentication.java:304|No X.509 cert selected for EdDSA
2023-09-12 22:14:01,279 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) javax.net.ssl|ALL|DC|default task-2|2023-09-12 22:14:01.279 UTC|X509Authentication.java:304|No X.509 cert selected for EC
2023-09-12 22:14:01,280 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) javax.net.ssl|ALL|DC|default task-2|2023-09-12 22:14:01.280 UTC|X509Authentication.java:304|No X.509 cert selected for EdDSA
2023-09-12 22:14:01,343 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-4) javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|86|default I/O-4|2023-09-12 22:14:01.343 UTC|Alert.java:238|Received alert message (
2023-09-12 22:14:01,345 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-4) "Alert": {
2023-09-12 22:14:01,345 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-4)   "level"      : "fatal",
2023-09-12 22:14:01,345 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-4)   "description": "certificate_unknown"
2023-09-12 22:14:01,345 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-4) }
2023-09-12 22:14:01,345 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-4) )
2023-09-12 22:14:01,347 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-4) javax.net.ssl|ERROR|86|default I/O-4|2023-09-12 22:14:01.346 UTC|TransportContext.java:370|Fatal (CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN): Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown (
2023-09-12 22:14:01,348 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-4) "throwable" : {
2023-09-12 22:14:01,349 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-4)   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
2023-09-12 22:14:01,349 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-4)      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,349 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-4)      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,349 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-4)      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:365)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,349 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-4)      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:293)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,349 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-4)      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:204)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,350 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-4)      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,350 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-4)      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.decode(SSLEngineImpl.java:736)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,350 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-4)      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:691)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,351 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-4)      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:506)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,351 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-4)      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:482)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,351 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-4)      at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.server.protocol.http.ALPNLimitingSSLEngine.unwrap(ALPNLimitingSSLEngine.java:142)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,352 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-4)      at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.protocols.ssl.SslConduit.doUnwrap(SslConduit.java:762)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,352 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-4)      at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.protocols.ssl.SslConduit.read(SslConduit.java:587)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,352 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-4)      at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.5.Final//org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSourceChannel.read(ConduitStreamSourceChannel.java:127)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,352 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-4)      at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.server.protocol.http.AlpnOpenListener$AlpnConnectionListener.handleEvent(AlpnOpenListener.java:356)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,352 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-4)      at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.server.protocol.http.AlpnOpenListener$AlpnConnectionListener.handleEvent(AlpnOpenListener.java:341)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,352 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-4)      at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.5.Final//org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,352 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-4)      at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.5.Final//org.xnio.conduits.ReadReadyHandler$ChannelListenerHandler.readReady(ReadReadyHandler.java:66)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,352 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-4)      at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.protocols.ssl.SslConduit$SslReadReadyHandler.readReady(SslConduit.java:1254)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,352 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-4)      at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.protocols.ssl.SslConduit$1.run(SslConduit.java:183)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,353 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-4)      at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.protocols.ssl.SslConduit$2.run(SslConduit.java:198)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,353 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-4)      at org.jboss.xnio.nio@3.8.5.Final//org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.safeRun(WorkerThread.java:612)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,353 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-4)      at org.jboss.xnio.nio@3.8.5.Final//org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:479)}
2023-09-12 22:14:01,353 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-4) 
2023-09-12 22:14:01,353 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-4) )
2023-09-12 22:14:01,354 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-1) javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|56|default I/O-1|2023-09-12 22:14:01.326 UTC|Alert.java:238|Received alert message (
2023-09-12 22:14:01,354 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-1) "Alert": {
2023-09-12 22:14:01,354 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-1)   "level"      : "fatal",
2023-09-12 22:14:01,354 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-1)   "description": "certificate_unknown"
2023-09-12 22:14:01,357 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-1) }
2023-09-12 22:14:01,357 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-1) )
2023-09-12 22:14:01,359 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-1) javax.net.ssl|ERROR|56|default I/O-1|2023-09-12 22:14:01.359 UTC|TransportContext.java:370|Fatal (CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN): Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown (
2023-09-12 22:14:01,360 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-1) "throwable" : {
2023-09-12 22:14:01,360 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-1)   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
2023-09-12 22:14:01,361 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-1)      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,366 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-1)      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,367 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-1)      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:365)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,367 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-1)      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:293)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,368 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-1)      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:204)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,368 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-1)      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,368 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-1)      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.decode(SSLEngineImpl.java:736)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,368 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-1)      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:691)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,368 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-1)      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:506)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,368 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-1)      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:482)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,368 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-1)      at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:679)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,368 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-1)      at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.server.protocol.http.ALPNLimitingSSLEngine.unwrap(ALPNLimitingSSLEngine.java:75)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,368 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-1)      at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.protocols.ssl.SslConduit.doUnwrap(SslConduit.java:781)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,368 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-1)      at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.protocols.ssl.SslConduit.doHandshake(SslConduit.java:672)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,368 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-1)      at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.protocols.ssl.SslConduit.access$900(SslConduit.java:70)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,368 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-1)      at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.protocols.ssl.SslConduit$SslReadReadyHandler.readReady(SslConduit.java:1215)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,372 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-1)      at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.protocols.ssl.SslConduit$1.run(SslConduit.java:183)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,372 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-1)      at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.protocols.ssl.SslConduit$2.run(SslConduit.java:198)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,372 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-1)      at org.jboss.xnio.nio@3.8.5.Final//org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.safeRun(WorkerThread.java:612)
2023-09-12 22:14:01,372 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-1)      at org.jboss.xnio.nio@3.8.5.Final//org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:479)}
2023-09-12 22:14:01,372 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-1) 
2023-09-12 22:14:01,372 ERROR [stderr] (default I/O-1) )
2023-09-12 22:17:06,808 INFO  [org.ejbca.core.ejb.services.ServiceSessionBean] (EJB default - 1) Timer was triggered. Trying to run service with ID 0.

```

These are the steps i took:

***1. Generated a CA with ejbca and a keystore using this command***
```
ant runinstall -Dappserver.home=/opt/kais/mes/install/guardian/wildfly/wildfly-26.0.0.Final 
ant deploy-keystore -Dappserver.home=/opt/kais/mes/install/guardian/wildfly/wildfly-26.0.0.Final 
```
***2. Regarding the CA installation, this is the install.properties:***
```
#
# $Id$
#
# This is a sample file to override default properties used
# during installation of EJBCA (ant install)
# 
# You should copy and rename this file to install.properties
# and customize at will.
#

# ------------ Administrative CA configuration ---------------------
# This installation will create a first Management CA. This CA will be used to create the first
# superadministrator and for the SSL server certificate of administrative web server.
# When the administrative web server have been setup you can create other CA:s and administrators.
# This is only used for administrative purposes,
# Enter a short name for the Management CA.
ca.name=KontronCA

# The Distinguished Name of the Management CA. 
# This is used in the CA certificate to distinguish the CA.
# Note, you can not use DC components for the initial CA, you can create CAs 
# using DC components later on once the CA GU is up and running.
ca.dn=CN=KontronCA,O=Kontron,C=MK

# The token type the administrative CA will use.
# Use soft for software generated keys (default) or enter a class path for the HSM class.
# Normally the HSM class should be the PKCS11CryptoToken. For Utimaco CP5, use Pkcs11NgCryptoToken.
#
# Possible values are:
# soft
# org.cesecore.keys.token.PKCS11CryptoToken
# org.cesecore.keys.token.p11ng.cryptotoken.Pkcs11NgCryptoToken
# se.primeKey.caToken.card.PrimeCAToken
# Note: If you use JBoss 7/EAP 6 and want to use PKCS#11 you have to configure JBoss to permit this. 
#       See instructions in the Install Guide.
#
# Default: soft
ca.tokentype=soft

# Password for the Management CA token.
# With soft token, use password null.
# To prompt for the password on the terminal, don't set, i.e. comment out the line below.
# If no password should be used (for example nCipher module protected), use password '' (nothing).
ca.tokenpassword=null

# Configuration file were you define key name, password and key alias for the HSM used 
# by the Management CA. Same as the Hard CA Token Properties in CA UI.
# Remove everything in the file and add your own configuration.
# Note that this must be a full path.
# On windows use / instead of \
#ca.tokenproperties=/home/ejbca/ejbca/conf/catoken.properties

# The keyspec for the administrative CAs key, to be generated in soft keystore.
# Keyspec for RSA keys is size of RSA keys (1024, 2048, 4096, 8192).
# Keyspec for ECDSA keys is name of curve or 'implicitlyCA', see docs.
ca.keyspec=2048

# The keytype for the Management CA, can be RSA, ECDSA or DSA
# For the key to be generated in soft keystore.
ca.keytype=RSA

# Default signing algorithm for the Management CA.
# Available algorithms are:
# SHA1WithRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA256WithRSA, SHA256withECDSA.
ca.signaturealgorithm=SHA256WithRSA

# The validity in days for the Management CA, only digits.
ca.validity=3650

# The policy id of the Management CA. Policy id determines which PKI policy the CA uses.
# Type your policy id or use '2.5.29.32.0' for 'any policy' (rfc5280) or 'null' for no policy at all.
ca.policy=null

# Certificate profile used for the CA certificate created during 'ant install'. 
# If you have a certificate profile imported you can use that. Otherwise default
# profile for ROOTCA is used.
# Default: ROOTCA
#ca.certificateprofile=MyOwnRootCACertificateProfile

```
***3.*** These commands generated a keystore and a truststore in the **Wildfly** keystore directory, also generated a **superadmin.p12** file in the **EJBCA** p12 directory. I imported the superadmin.p12 cert into my browser to correspond to the contents of the Wildfly keystore. For those who could use the contents of the certificates/keys in detail:***

* **keystore**:

```
Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: guardian
Creation date: Sep 12, 2023
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 2
Certificate[1]:
Owner: C=MK, O=Kontron, CN=guardian
Issuer: C=MK, O=Kontron, CN=KontronCA
Serial number: 35fa3d026c4f457ce7395000d2c3a3303f61a316
Valid from: Tue Sep 12 21:25:35 UTC 2023 until: Thu Sep 11 21:16:03 UTC 2025
Certificate fingerprints:
         SHA1: 41:34:F5:8E:35:97:29:52:92:30:86:A5:B1:D7:75:94:AB:BA:F3:85
         SHA256: D3:85:48:65:1C:72:51:BD:53:29:2C:A2:9A:FA:2D:F2:4F:C4:89:91:EE:CB:5F:0B:9F:79:BB:A7:39:A3:6A:67
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 3

Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: F2 E9 49 59 83 CC EB F7   ED 57 B4 D1 EC 26 E8 44  ..IY.....W...&.D
0010: 50 69 6D FB                                        Pim.
]
]

#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
]

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  serverAuth
]

#4: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_Encipherment
]

#5: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: guardian
]

#6: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 1F C8 84 02 3A 27 5D 87   69 7F 0B F9 C7 49 7A 90  ....:'].i....Iz.
0010: 1B A3 AC F1                                        ....
]
]

Certificate[2]:
Owner: C=MK, O=Kontron, CN=KontronCA
Issuer: C=MK, O=Kontron, CN=KontronCA
Serial number: 469c953c2abc88fe22cfd0e196233597c49ca7dd
Valid from: Tue Sep 12 21:25:35 UTC 2023 until: Fri Sep 09 21:25:34 UTC 2033
Certificate fingerprints:
         SHA1: BB:16:7B:4E:A7:F1:3F:0F:0E:2E:46:AE:22:53:B9:79:D8:FC:40:84
         SHA256: 2F:63:73:96:ED:7A:70:ED:89:07:37:87:2E:60:0F:03:EE:9F:0C:F8:E9:25:5A:71:11:4D:67:5B:0F:EB:86:0A
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 3

Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: F2 E9 49 59 83 CC EB F7   ED 57 B4 D1 EC 26 E8 44  ..IY.....W...&.D
0010: 50 69 6D FB                                        Pim.
]
]

#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen: no limit
]

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_CertSign
  Crl_Sign
]

#4: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: F2 E9 49 59 83 CC EB F7   ED 57 B4 D1 EC 26 E8 44  ..IY.....W...&.D
0010: 50 69 6D FB                                        Pim.
]
]



*******************************************
*******************************************

```

* **truststore**:

```
Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: kontronca
Creation date: Sep 12, 2023
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

Owner: C=MK, O=Kontron, CN=KontronCA
Issuer: C=MK, O=Kontron, CN=KontronCA
Serial number: 469c953c2abc88fe22cfd0e196233597c49ca7dd
Valid from: Tue Sep 12 21:25:35 UTC 2023 until: Fri Sep 09 21:25:34 UTC 2033
Certificate fingerprints:
         SHA1: BB:16:7B:4E:A7:F1:3F:0F:0E:2E:46:AE:22:53:B9:79:D8:FC:40:84
         SHA256: 2F:63:73:96:ED:7A:70:ED:89:07:37:87:2E:60:0F:03:EE:9F:0C:F8:E9:25:5A:71:11:4D:67:5B:0F:EB:86:0A
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 3

Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: F2 E9 49 59 83 CC EB F7   ED 57 B4 D1 EC 26 E8 44  ..IY.....W...&.D
0010: 50 69 6D FB                                        Pim.
]
]

#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen: no limit
]

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_CertSign
  Crl_Sign
]

#4: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: F2 E9 49 59 83 CC EB F7   ED 57 B4 D1 EC 26 E8 44  ..IY.....W...&.D
0010: 50 69 6D FB                                        Pim.
]
]



*******************************************
*******************************************

```

* **superadmin.p12**:

```
Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: superadmin
Creation date: Sep 12, 2023
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 2
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=SuperAdmin
Issuer: C=MK, O=Kontron, CN=KontronCA
Serial number: 7d746d2654d61e218a9ee97737ba641410486529
Valid from: Tue Sep 12 21:25:35 UTC 2023 until: Thu Sep 11 21:16:30 UTC 2025
Certificate fingerprints:
         SHA1: 34:62:62:9E:D1:75:DB:69:BF:95:70:99:6D:01:7D:B9:47:28:D3:3E
         SHA256: 16:37:E9:59:C1:E0:60:1C:0B:4A:10:C7:F2:CF:C2:18:48:0B:82:31:81:5F:6A:1F:B8:AF:1E:5A:BF:C6:9D:9E
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 3

Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: F2 E9 49 59 83 CC EB F7   ED 57 B4 D1 EC 26 E8 44  ..IY.....W...&.D
0010: 50 69 6D FB                                        Pim.
]
]

#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
]

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  clientAuth
  emailProtection
]

#4: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Non_repudiation
  Key_Encipherment
]

#5: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 86 CB BD 08 52 E3 44 52   F5 FB 63 79 C2 93 41 08  ....R.DR..cy..A.
0010: 86 98 E7 A5                                        ....
]
]

Certificate[2]:
Owner: C=MK, O=Kontron, CN=KontronCA
Issuer: C=MK, O=Kontron, CN=KontronCA
Serial number: 469c953c2abc88fe22cfd0e196233597c49ca7dd
Valid from: Tue Sep 12 21:25:35 UTC 2023 until: Fri Sep 09 21:25:34 UTC 2033
Certificate fingerprints:
         SHA1: BB:16:7B:4E:A7:F1:3F:0F:0E:2E:46:AE:22:53:B9:79:D8:FC:40:84
         SHA256: 2F:63:73:96:ED:7A:70:ED:89:07:37:87:2E:60:0F:03:EE:9F:0C:F8:E9:25:5A:71:11:4D:67:5B:0F:EB:86:0A
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 3

Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: F2 E9 49 59 83 CC EB F7   ED 57 B4 D1 EC 26 E8 44  ..IY.....W...&.D
0010: 50 69 6D FB                                        Pim.
]
]

#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen: no limit
]

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_CertSign
  Crl_Sign
]

#4: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: F2 E9 49 59 83 CC EB F7   ED 57 B4 D1 EC 26 E8 44  ..IY.....W...&.D
0010: 50 69 6D FB                                        Pim.
]
]



*******************************************
*******************************************

```

**4.** Tried to connect to the server and got the following error, I tried many solutions but I am out of ideas. Id appreciate your help, thank you.
````

Comment: Your certificate contain the entry `SubjectAlternativeName [ DNSName: guardian ]`. Therefore the certificate is not suitable for a server accessed via `10.0.0.16` as it is not `guardian`. The address you use in the URL has to be present in the certificate!

Comment: Thank you, Is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: @Robert it still does not work, I added the guardian host to known hosts, still "Certificate uknown"

Comment: It doesn't matter what you add where unless the IP address is not added into the SubjectAlternativeName extension within the certificate or you use a different URL. If you use the IP address in the URL it has to be present in the certificate. Most likely the server tries to find a matching certificate for 10.0.0.16 but fails.

Answer (score 0):

For a browser session invalid hostname does not give errors like that, you would get a browser warning and the option to accept the danger and continue.
Verify your TLS setup by going to port 8442 forst, which is server-ceritficate-only TLS. If that works, going to port 8443 should have your browser ask you for the client certificate to use.
What browser do you use? The browser may have cached failed attempt (without client cert installed in browser), so you should try a new private window (or restart browser).